# Xpath to get an 'id' or 'counter' of which loop number I'm on for a given xpath expression

Tags: xpath

Updated based on feedback, thanks -

I have an example such as below, where while parsing the xpath I would like to keep track of which row I'm on /rows/row via a number or identifier.  I'm currently trying to transfer the XML into a relational format and have each set of columns identified with the 'Row ID',row number, or row position that it came from.

```
<rows>
<row>
<columns>
<column>
<name>x</name>
<value>val1.x</value>
</column>
<column>
<name>y</name>
<value>val1.y</value>
</column>
<column>
<name>z</name>
<value>val1.z</value>
</column>
</columns>
</row>
<row>
<columns>
<column>
<name>x</name>
<value>val2.x</value>
</column>
<column>
<name>y</name>
<value>val2.y</value>
</column>
<column>
<name>z</name>
<value>val2.z</value>
</column>
</columns>
</row>
<row>
<column>
<name>x</name>
<value>val3.x</value>
</column>
<column>
<name>y</name>
<value>val3.y</value>
</column>
<column>
<name>z</name>
<value>val3.z</value>
</column>
</columns>
</row>
</rows>
```

Comment: I am a bit unclear as to what you mean by *'group' the rows*. Can you explain further? Perhaps position() would help? http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#context

Comment: So, what is the question? What is your current XPath expression? Please, edit your question and provide the missing information.

Comment: "I'm using a tool to parse the xml via xpath expressions." - What is the tool?

Comment: It looks as if you're looking for the position() function, but your question is very vague.

Comment: 18 hrs. later the question is equally unclear -- in fact there is no question...

Comment: Maybe I can't formulate/make it clear because I'm unsure of the correct terminology.    For each 'row', instead I want to get the number it is (val1.* rows are 'row 1', val2.* rows are 'row 2'.)  Question: How to get the row number?

Comment: You should edit your question and show us the wanted selected nodes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find position of a node using xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226405/find-position-of-a-node-using-xpath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your context node is a `<value>`, `<name>`, `<column>` or `<columns>` element and `<row>` elements are not in this document outside the current structure. Then the following XPath will give you the "row number"

```
count(ancestor::row) + count(ancestor::row[1]/preceding-sibling::row)
```

Indexing begins at `1`. If the expression returns `0`, the context node is not inside the row structure.

Comment: thanks, count w/ preceding-sibling gives the number of the row