# XML - string which is equal to one of the attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to check if there is a string which is equal to one of the attributes. For instances:

```
<rules>
        <mother cat="pp">
            <daughter cat="pr"/>
            <daughter cat="np"/>
        </mother>
        <mother cat="wp">
            <daughter cat="rp"/>
            <daughter cat="vp"/>
        </mother>
        <mother cat="cn">
            <daughter cat="jj"/>
            <daughter cat="cn"/>
        </mother>
        <mother cat="np">
            <daughter cat="jj"/>
            <daughter cat="np"/>
        </mother>
    </rules>
```

I just need to test if "pp" is equal to one of the mothers' cat attribute.
For this example yes it is. But it should be false for "pr".

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following expression:

```
/*/mother[@cat='pp']
```

This expression returns the `mother` element having an attribute named `cat` whose value is equal to `pp`.

In an `xsl:if` test expression, this will return `true` if such a node exists; false, otherwise. For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test="/*/mother[@cat='pp']">NODE EXISTS</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet prints `NODE EXISTS` only when such a node is present in the source.

Find this element's position using the following expression:

```
count(/*/mother[@cat='pp']/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```

Comment: and how can i find the position of that mother for example for pp it should be 1. i tried count preceding-sibling but didnt work out..

Comment: @user446141 - Something like this: `count(/*/mother[@cat='pp']/preceding-sibling::*)+1.`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226405/find-position-of-a-node-using-xpath

Answer (score 1):

This XPath syntax will work for your case...

```
//mother[@cat='pp']
```

It will return any `mother` nodes that have the value "pp" in the `cat` attribute. Otherwise, if you were testing

```
//mother[@cat='pr']
```

Then you would get an empty node set back.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<xsl:if test="//mother[@cat = 'pp']">
  <xsl:message terminate="no">
    Exists!
  </xsl:message>
</xsl:if>
```

Will print `Exists!` If there is at least one mother with `@cat = 'pp'`.

Answer (score 0):

> I just need to test if "pp" is equal to one of the mothers' cat
>   attribute.

Good question, +1.

**Simpler than all other present answers**:

```
/*/mother/@cat = 'pp'
```

This evaluates to `true()` exactly in the case when there `"pp"` is equal to the string value of a `cat` attribute of a `mother` element, that is a child of the top element of the XML document.

> For this example yes it is. But it should be false for "pr".

**Once again, evaluate**:

```
/*/mother/@cat = 'pr'
```

**Below is a simple transformation showing this in action**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  /*/mother/@cat = 'pp' is <xsl:text/>
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/mother/@cat = 'pp'"/>

  /*/mother/@cat = 'pr' is <xsl:text/>
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/mother/@cat = 'pr'"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<rules>
    <mother cat="pp">
        <daughter cat="pr"/>
        <daughter cat="np"/>
    </mother>
    <mother cat="wp">
        <daughter cat="rp"/>
        <daughter cat="vp"/>
    </mother>
    <mother cat="cn">
        <daughter cat="jj"/>
        <daughter cat="cn"/>
    </mother>
    <mother cat="np">
        <daughter cat="jj"/>
        <daughter cat="np"/>
    </mother>
</rules>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  /*/mother/@cat = 'pp' is true

  /*/mother/@cat = 'pr' is false
```