# Finding the position index of a comment()

Tags: xpath

Faced with this:

```
<div>
some text
<!-- this is the hook comment-->
target part 1
target part 2
<!-- this is another comment-->
some other text
</div>
```

I'm trying to get to the desired output of:

> target part 1
>   target part 2

The number of comments and text elements is unknown, but the target text always comes after the comment containing `hook`. So the idea is to find the `position()` of the relevant `comment()`, and get the next element.

There are some previous questions about [finding the position of an element containing a certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226405/find-position-of-a-node-using-xpath) or [by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589469/find-position-of-a-node-using-xpath-using-attributes), but `comment()` is an odd duck and I can't modify the answers there to this situation. For example, trying a variation on the answers:

```
//comment()[contains(string(),'hook')]/preceding::*
```

or using `preceding-sibling::*`, returns nothing.

So I decided to try something else. A `count(//node())` of the xml returns `6`. And `//node()[2]` returns the relevant `comment()`. But when I try to get the position of that comment by using `index-of()` (which should return `2`)

```
index-of(//node(),//comment()[contains(string(),'hook')])
```

it returns `3`!

Of course, I can disregard that and use the `3` index position as the position for the target text (instead of incrementing `2` by 1), but I was wondering, first, why is the outcome what it is and, second, does it have any unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to firstly find the `position()` of the elements if you want to get the nodes between two comments (FYI `position()` depends on the whole nodeset you selected).

You can get the elements directly - here they are `text()` nodes. So a sample file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <div>
    some text
    <!-- this is the hook comment-->
    target part 1
    target part 2
    <!-- this is another comment-->
    some other text
        <!-- this is another comment-->
    no one needs this
        <!-- this is another comment-->
    this is also useless
        <!-- this is another hook comment-->
    second target text
        <!-- this is another comment-->
    again some useless crap
        <!-- this is another comment-->
    and the last piece that noone needs
    </div> 
</root>
```

can be queried with the following expression

```
//comment()[contains(string(),'hook')]/following-sibling::text()[preceding-sibling::comment()[1][contains(string(),'hook')]]
```

to result in

```
target part 1
target part 2

second target text
```

If you only want the first block, restrict the expression to the first item:

```
(//comment()[contains(string(),'hook')]/following-sibling::text()[preceding-sibling::comment()[1][contains(string(),'hook')]])[1]
```

Its result is

```
target part 1
target part 2
```

as desired.

---

If you can use XPath-2.0, you can append a `/position()` to the expressions above to get the position of the `comment()`s. But, as mentioned above, they are relative to comment nodes. So the result would be `1 2`.

Comment: Those expressions make your head spin but sure do work! Thanks.