# XPath: returning the index of specific tag inside a set of tags with the same type

Tags: xpath

Here is an excerpt of my xml:

```
<table>
    ...
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I know how to find specific `<tr>` tag.

Is it possible to define `<tr>` tag index or ordinal number inside the `<tbody>` tag? I guess, that it's possible to loop through the table, but the table is quite large and it will take lots of time.

Is it possible to get this index/ordinal number with single XPATH statement?

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226405/find-position-of-a-node-using-xpath help? something like `count(.//tr[...]/preceding-sibling::tr)+1` (with `...` being your predicate to select the `tr` you want)

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I've found the answer following the link provided by you

Comment: Cool. Could you post your own answer to help others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used following XPath expression:

```
//tbody//td[text()='findMe']/../following-sibling::tr
```

These expression calculates, how many 'tr' nodes are located under the node with 'findMe' text. Actually, it useful, because quantity of 'tr' nodes could be obtained.

But, prior to given XPath, a verification should be made, because in case 'finMe' string would be absent, XPath would return 0. The following expression works as validation fine:

```
//tbody//td[text()='findMe']
```