# XSLT - find the position of an element where element names differ

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, position

I'm trying to find the position of the `<b>` element (which I'd expect to be 2) in the below XML using XSLT:

```
<root>
  <a>
    ...
  </a>
  <b>
    ...
  </b>
</root>
```

I'm trying to retrieve this value during a for-each loop through `root/*`.

Based on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226405/find-position-of-a-node-using-xpath), I've tried using: `count(root/b/preceding-sibling::*)+1` but all I seem to get is the value '1'. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where exactly are you when you use the above expression? XSLT is very much context-dependent.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, please see my updated question. I'm trying to retrieve this value whilst looping through the children of `root`. In reality, I have more than 2 child elements of `root`, so I'm trying to figure out how to find the position of element 'x' whilst focusing on element 'y' in my loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to retrieve this value during a for-each loop through
>   root/*.

As I suspected, this is a context issue. During your loop, you are either in the context of `<a>` or of `<b>`. In both cases, the **relative** path `root/b/...` selects nothing. You may have more success using an **absolute** path:

```
 count(/root/b/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```