# identify the content of xml using header value in sql

Tags: sql, xml

```
DECLARE @xml xml=' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><text>
              <table>
                 <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>a</th>
                       <th>b</th>
                       <th>c</th>
                       <th>d</th>
                       <th>e</th>
                       <th>f</th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    <tr>
                       <td>testa1</td>
                       <td>testb1</td>
                       <td>testc1</td>
                       <td>testd1</td>
                       <td>teste1</td>
                       <td>testf1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>testa1</td>
                       <td>testb1</td>
                       <td>testc1</td>
                       <td>testd1</td>
                       <td>teste1</td>
                       <td>testf1</td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
              </table>
           </text>'

SELECT 
    T.c.value('(tbody/tr/td)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS a
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('text/table[thead[tr[th="b"]]]') AS t(c)
```

This query selects only the first body contents from xml.

Here I want to select only the values under header b

Comment: What **RDBMS** are you using? Please add a relevant tag, like `mysql`, `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server` since those database systems all support XML - yet all slightly differently ...

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the xpath as follows will do it:

```
 SELECT T.c.value('/text/table/tbody/tr/td[position()=2]','VARCHAR(100)') AS a
```

Explanation:

Selects the second `td` element among a list of siblings.

Note:

Combine that with [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227080) to get:

```
    SELECT T.c.value('/text/table/tbody/tr/td[position() = count(/text/table/tbody/tr/th[text() = "b"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS a
```