# Find the number(position) of a node in list

Tags: python, xpath

In xpath how can I find which number (depending on where, 0 or 1, you start, **c** is either 2 or 3) is for example item **c** in the following list:

```
<ol>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226405/find-position-of-a-node-using-xpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) and [count the preceding `li` siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227080/771848):

```
count(//ol/li[. = 'c']/preceding-sibling::*)
```

Demo (using [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)):

```
>>> from lxml import etree as ET
>>> data = """
... <ol>
... <li>a</li>
... <li>b</li>
... <li>c</li>
... <li>d</li>
... </ol>
... """
>>> tree = ET.fromstring(data)
>>> value = "c"
>>> int(tree.xpath("count(//ol/li[. = '%s']/preceding-sibling::li)" % value))
2
```

Comment: Can li[@id="something"] be used with the [. = '%s']? Thanks

Comment: @abruski sure, you can filter the desired element using text, attribute or any other method - the key trick is to use `preceding-sibling::li` to count the preceding li elements.