# How to write an xpath to select data from a certain column in an HTML table when the column may shift positions?

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, testng

[image: Example Table Column]

```
List<WebElement> clmnValue = driver.fintElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[1]"));
```

I'm trying to crate xpath for "Brand Name" which will store all the value under the "Brand Name"
.. each time When i refresh "Brand Name" move to another column[its Dynamic not stay in 1column] but name remain unchanged.
Need Help to crate xpath which will store all the Brand Name value in to the list.
Thank you all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant HTML code as a code block, including the Java code you have already tried.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Ok. That's a start. Please include the relevant HTML code as well.

Comment: And please include more information about the expected behavior. Do you want a `List<String>` where each item in the list is the name of a brand?

Comment: Im trying to crate the xpath which will store the full column, when its dynamicly move that xpath will work  for all time,. I can do they rest.

Comment: I cannot recommend an XPath **until I see the HTML**.

Comment: //tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[1] would select all tds under column 1,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input looks something like this.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Brand Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Samsung</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LG</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Motorolla</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Starting from this answer:

[Find position of a node using xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226405/find-position-of-a-node-using-xpath)

We can count which position the desired column is in:

`count(//tbody/tr/th[contains(., "Brand Name")]/preceding-sibling::th) + 1`

Then we can then substitute it for the `1` in your example, creating an xpath that selects every cell in a row at that same position.

`//tbody/tr/td[count(//tbody/tr/th[contains(., "Brand Name")]/preceding-sibling::th) + 1]`

Testing the xpath with `lxml` in iPython:

```
In [47]: root.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[count(//tbody/tr/th[contains(., "Brand Name")]/preceding-sibling::th) + 1]')
Out[47]: 
[<Element td at 0x7f887c48b700>,
 <Element td at 0x7f887c89ef80>,
 <Element td at 0x7f887c5fe2c0>,
 <Element td at 0x7f887c50e580>]

In [48]: root.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[count(//tbody/tr/th[contains(., "Brand Name")]/preceding-sibling::th) + 1]/text()')
Out[48]: ['Apple', 'Samsung', 'LG', 'Motorolla']
```